# How can i add key/value to object queryset

Tags: django, dictionary, django-queryset

I need to add key/value to queryset per each object based on stuff in request.session.

How to do that?

Alan

Comment: Actually, this question was bit stupid. What i needed was this:
object= Object.objects.all()
and in for loop :object.session = request.session[object.id]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historical answer:

You can use the `.extra()` method on a queryset to add extra 'fields'.

There is some [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#extra) that may be useful.

New answer:

You should use the `.annotate()` method to add extra fields.

View the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#annotate).